# Selenium WebDriver - google account login problem using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

When I try to log into my google account, it shows me the message as in the screenshot below.
Please advise how to log into my google account without any issue.

[image]

I tried so many times and I tried using undetected_webdriver but it still doesn't work.

When I use undetected_cromedriver it shows this error

```
File "C:\Users\Md Nishad Islam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 778, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Md Nishad Islam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 733, in quit
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```